# Access data from route on next page.Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

How could access data from this

```
<a  href="{{ route('players.create',$post->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
```

I got this `/players/create?3` in my next page.

Comment: Welcome! Please give more detail so we can better understand what you are asking. Is your code giving an error? Let us know which error, and what line of code causes it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array with key/value, like this:

```
<a  href="{{ route('players.create',['id' => $post->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
```

And then, in the controller, you can get as

```
public function create($request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id'); //$id = 3
    //do something
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route